# Delphi scaling with ScaleBy and Margin

Tags: delphi

I am trying to scale my form for highdpi monitors. I tried to do it automatically with `Scaled := True` and also manually with `Scaled := False` and calling `ScaleBy`.

It seems that the value of `Margin` (e.g. for `TSpeedButton`) has not changed and the text now appears somehwere else.

I positioned the `TLabel` and the `TSpeedButton` under each other and adjusted the `Margin` of the `TSpeedButton` so that the text starts at the same pixel. Works at 96dpi (100%).

But scaling of the form is repositioning the `TLabel` and the `Margin` stays untouched. Is that correct or a bug?

Is overriding ChangeScale in tMySpeedButton the only way to solve that?

Comment: including your delphi version would be helpful as the DPI awareness has changed per version..

Comment: Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3